# HTML / CSS Body Content Border

Tags: html, css, border

I am trying to add a full body border around my left-content and right-content classes.

I have my bottom border on my headings h4 acting as the bodies top border, simply because I like the disconnected look.

I then have a left, right and bottom border on my .left-content class.

I am using the right & bottom borders as "content separators".

Below my bottom border I want to have my "Customer testimonials" and then my social media footer below that.

But my problem is, on the left and right of my left-content class, I have a 3% padding, to push the content away from the border a bit.

I then tried to add a margin-left aswell as a padding-left of 3% to my .right-content class, but it isnt being effected by them at all and I cannot recreate the same spacing.

So my questions are, How can I get a full body border around both my left and right content classes all being the same size?

Also how can I recreate the spacing onto the .right-content class as I have with the .left-content class.

Any help is much appreciated, thank you very much!

Also, all the text on my site is just copy and pasted. I'm just building random sites for fun right now trying to learn more.

JSFiddle of my HTML & CSS code:

https://jsfiddle.net/Lvjz8z8n/

html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sample</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div class="content">

<!-- site header -->
<header class="main-header">
<img id="spark-logo" src="sparkinc.jpg">
<h4 id="title-quote">The lowest prices anywhere!</h4>
</header>

<!-- left side content -->
<div class="left-content">
<h2 id="left-title">How are we able to keep our prices so low?</h2>
<h3 id="eco-scale">Economies of Scale</h3>
    <p>Economies of scale reduce the per-unit costs without requiring product quality reductions. Larger orders of materials and components come with discounts, as do increases in total shipping. Simple experience in manufacturing a product teaches the business about the process and lets it use those insights to improve efficiency and trim waste, which reduces cost. Hiring expert help, such as managers, and technological improvements, such as new machinery and automation, also improve efficiency and reduce per-unit costs.</p>
<h3 id="eco-scope">Economies of Scope</h3>
    <p>Economies of scope, like economies of scale, also reduce costs, but through production of a wider range of products. Related products often require many of the same materials, creating an incidental economy of scale, and the same machinery to produce them. This allows the business to use the same production facility to make two marketable products, often with a minimal investment. Businesses experience economies of scope in marketing and advertising by promoting a brand or product line, rather than a single product. Vertical supply chain integration – when one business owns multiple pieces of the supply chain -- can create economies of scope through cost reduction and improved management efficiency.</p>
<h3 id="man-system">Institure a Quality Management System</h3>
    <p>Specific quality management systems focus on somewhat different elements. Lean, for example, emphasizes minimizing waste across the organization, while Six Sigma offers a data-driven approach to defect reduction. Quality management systems provide businesses with tested approaches for process improvements, efficiency boosts and cost reduction. Deploying a quality management system helps a business deliver its products at a lower cost, which keeps prices down and still allows the business to offer higher-quality products. In addition to Lean and Six Sigma, popular quality management systems include ISO, total quality management and business process re-engineering.</p>
<h3 id="consideration">Considerations</h3>
    <p>Taking advantage of economies of scale and scope depends on sufficient demand in the marketplace for the product. Scaling up operations, product diversification and acquisition of other businesses only makes sense if doing so promises to deliver a sufficient return on investment. Businesses also need to remain vigilant for diseconomies of scale and scope, in which scaling up production or diversification creates inefficiencies that drive up costs.</p>
</div>

<!-- right side content -->
<div class="right-content">
<h2 id="right-title">So what does this mean for YOU?</h2>
    <p>We pride ourselves on providing the lowest everyday domain prices on the Internet. We are able to offer such low prices due to our focus on domains and nothing else. We do not incur the expensive overhead associated with the infrastructure, staff and promotion of other ancillary services. We do not need to inflate our pricing to cover costs such as expensive celebrity spokespeople, vanity phone numbers, Super Bowl advertising, or non-domain-related technical and support staff. There are certain costs associated with running an effective domain registrar, but we are fanatical about avoiding non-essential expenses which allows us to keep our prices so low. We are in the domain business and no other!

    We also do not utilize the backend platform of any other registrar. Many of our most notable competitors are reliant on systems developed and supported by third-parties. This has many potential problems and drawbacks including having to wait for upgrades, multiple parties being involved in domain disputes and other possible issues, and, most importantly, the fact that third-parties must be paid for their services which inflates the pricing to customers.

    Spending more on a domain elsewhere does not make it better. Registering a domain with us is no different than anywhere else... you register the domain of your choice, for the period of time you want, and we do this like anywhere else - just for less money and no nickel-and-diming for services that should be free!</p>
</div>

<!-- end border div  -->



<!-- testimonials -->
<div class="testimonials-quotes">
<footer id="testimonials">
    <h3>Want more proof of our services?</h3>
    <h4>Just ask our satisfied customers!</h4>
</footer>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS page:

```
  .content {
    margin: 3% 14%;
}

.main-header {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #C7CED1;
}

#spark-logo {
    width: 20%;
    margin-left: 3%;
}

#title-quote {
    font-size: 25px;
    margin-left: 3%;
    padding-bottom: 3%;
    font-family: 'Merriweather Sans', sans-serif;
}

.left-content {
    width: 46%;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 2%;
    border-left: 1px solid #D1E8F0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #D1E8F0;
    border-right: 1px solid #D1E8F0;
    padding: 0 3% 3%;
}

.left-content h2 {
    font-size: 1.5em;
}

#left-title {
    margin-bottom: 5%;
}

.left-content h3 {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    color: #3E4345;
}

#eco-scale {
    margin-bottom: 2%;
    text-align: center;
}

#eco-scope {
    margin-top: 2%;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
    text-align: center;
}

#man-system {
    margin-top: 2%;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
    text-align: center;
}

#consideration {
    margin-top: 2%;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
    text-align: center;
}

.right-content {
    border-right: 1px solid #D1E8F0;
    margin-top: 2%;
    margin-left: 3%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with borders is that they take the margins into consideration. You need to **only** use padding if you want the borders to occupy the full width.

What I believe you're looking for is to apply a `float` to the right-hand column, remove the margin, add some padding, and set a width that's based on these calculations:

```
.right-content {
  /* margin-left: 3%; */ /* removed */
  float: left;
  width: 41%;
  padding: 0 3% 3%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #D1E8F0;
}
```

Keep in mind that you'll also need to clear the `float` once you get to the 'footer' section:

```
.testimonials-quotes {
  clear: both;
}
```

I've created a JSFiddle showcasing this [**here**](https://jsfiddle.net/p3Lyrf7t/).

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

Using `box-sizing: border-box` makes the sizing much easier, as it takes borders and padding into calculation when defining an objects width.

Setting `box-sizing: border-box` allows:

```
.left-content,
.right-content {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 50%;
    border: 1px solid #d1e8f0;
    padding: 3%;
}

.left-content { float: left; }
.right-content {
    float: right;
    border-left: none; /* otherwise double border in middle */
}

.testimonials-quotes {
    clear: both;
}
```